# alert when the value of the button is submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery form wizard which I plugged to my website. What I am trying to do here is when the user reach the end point of the form, an alert in JavaScript popup to him. I tried this very simple  JavaScript code at the top of my page `<head>..some code</head>`

```
function alertme() {
    if (this.value = "Submit") {
        alert("welcome");
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

the HTML button that I am trying to run this function when the event `OnClick()` happen

```
<input class="navigation_button" id="next" value="Next" type="submit" onclick="alertme();" />
```

as you see the value now is `Next`, the problem here is my JavaScript function ignore the value and popup the alert whenever the button has been click during the form steps, how should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function alertme() {
    if (document.getElementById('next').value == "Submit") {
       alert("welcome");
    }
    else {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like your problem is in your second line of code.

You need a double equals. `this.value == "Submit"`

... you also needed to pass "this" in your function. Complete answer:

```
<input class="navigation_button" id="next" value="Next" type="submit" onclick="alertme(this);" />

function alertme(e) {
    if (e.value == "Submit") {
        alert("welcome");
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How did it not work? Is it not alerting when it should, or is it always alerting?